# BCS External List CRUD operation using REST API on SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, external-list, crud

Can we have CRUD operation on SharePoint External List Based on SQL Server using Rest API with Jquery on SharePoint 2013 On Premise. This [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/bcs-rest-api-reference-for-sharepoint) says it possible. But need more advice on this

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Rest API can do operation to External list like normal list, please see the demos about CRUD using Rest API：

[CRUD Operation On List Items Using REST API Services In SharePoint 2013](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operation-on-list-items-using-rest-api-services-in-shar/)

Comment: I did some POC but found many limitations. Major is that Primary key always returned a zero and also filter operations are not working REST API.