# SharePoint 2013 REST API filters

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest, api

As part of our requirement, i created one BCS connection which retrieves data from a SQL stored procedure which acceppts two input paramaters. I was able to create a external list out of it. But when i try to access the data using REST API i.e, 
https://siteurl/_api/Web/lists/GetByTitle('listname')/GetItems?$filter = Filter1 eq x and Filter2 eq 'xxxx' , i am unable to see any data.

If i provide the input from the view settings, i am able to see the data. The above url is working if i access a list which is connected to BCS entity with stored procedure having 1 input.

Could any one please let me know if there is any limitation for stored procedures with multiple parameters? Any information would be a great help..

Answer (score 0):

You are using endpoint incorrectly. GetItems endpoint must be used with CAML query param. Use "items" endpoint instead.
Like this:

```
https://siteurl/_api/Web/lists/GetByTitle('listname')/items?$filter = Filter1 eq x and Filter2 eq 'xxxx'
```

You can see this way in official [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest#retrieve-all-list-items).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Even GetItems is not working. Could you please let me know if there is any problem in the syntax or any limitation for this?

Comment: Try to see this link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/bcs-rest-api-reference-for-sharepoint. I always thought that with BCS lists we work same as with usual list. But there I see that endpoint different. Try to use this endpoint: http://[sharepointsite]/_api/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items   Here /web/ not exists in endpoint. And query options (like filter or select operator) without $-sign) but this thing may be mistyping.

Comment: or this link https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-access-external-data-with-rest-in-sharepoint

Comment: May be filtering is not working for BCS REST API. In this article: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/244530/bcs-external-list-crud-operation-using-rest-api-on-sharepoint-2013 someone said that had some limitations.

Comment: I think BCS REST API can have different endpoint without 'web' part or URL and has some limitation about filtering.